# Is the function continuous. I get it as continuous and discontinuous

Tags: calculus

Given $f(X)=\frac{X^2-X-2}{X-2}$ . Is it continuous?

What I did is simplifying it, and I get a continuous. But if I proceed without simplify, it is discontinued.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This situation is often referred to as [removable discontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Removable_discontinuity) at $X = 2$.

However, as the Wiki page points out, this is an abuse of notation and isn't completely correct since $f$ is continuous everywhere it is defined, i.e., on its natural domain $(-\infty,2)\cup(2,\infty) = \Bbb R - \{2\}$.

In order for it to truly be a removable discontinuity, the function must be defined at the point in question (the point must be in the domain of the function).

A more technically correct term for this situation is to call the point $X=2$ a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity).

Comment: This is not correct because you aren't told what $f(2)$ is. $2$ is not in the domain of the expression.

Comment: You are right. I've clarified my answer a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using real variables, this is a continuous function. The implicit maximal domain is $(-\infty,2)\cup(2,\infty)$. There is a "hole" in the domain at $2$; this does not make the function discontinuous there, only undefined there.

A function can't be continuous or discontinuous at a point that is not in its domain.

Technically you don't have a function until you specify a domain and a range as well as a rule of assignment. So we could take the range to be $(-\infty,\infty)$.

This function can be extended to all of $(-\infty,\infty)$ in many ways, but there is only one such extension which is continuous. That's because $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$ exists, and so we must define the extension at $2$ to be $f(2)= \lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=3$ to have continuity of the extension there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simplify it for $x=2$, because $f(2)=\frac{0}{0}$, then $f$ is discontinuous at $x=2$ because it is undefined at such point, however you can remove the discontinuity by defining $f(2)=3$ for $x=2$, that is why we called it 'removable discontinuity'

Comment: "Undefined" and "discontinuous" are definitely different concepts. The former applies here, the latter does not.

Comment: thank you for the correction, then, is this fuction discontinuous at $x=2$ or not?

Comment: If you haven't specified a value for $f(2)$, then the function is neither continuous nor discontinuous at $x=2$ -- rather, it is simply undefined at $x=2$. If you have specified that $f(2)=3$, then the extension is continuous at $x=2$. If you have specified that $f(2)$ is any other value, then the extension is discontinuous at $x=2$.

Comment: then, can we say the function is continuous in $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{2\}$?

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(X)$ is not defined in $X=2$ since the denominator $X-2$ is zero when $X=2$, so you cannot simplify this function as $$\frac{X^2-X-2}{X-2} = \frac{(X+1)(X-2)}{X-2} = X+1 .$$ Also, The domain of function is $(-\infty, 2) \cup (2, +\infty)$, so you can only discuss the discontinuity or continuity by the origin $f(X)$ instead of the simplified one.

Comment: Why I can't simplify it? Cause if I simplify, it will eventually become continuous

Comment: You cannot simplify since the function $f(X)$ is not defined in $X=2$. If you simplify this function, the simplified function states that it is defined in $X=2$, which is contradictory to the function before simplification.

Comment: In fact, he *can* simplify it. But the simplification invokes a caveat. The simplified function is $$f(x)=x+1 \textrm{  }(x\neq 2)$$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you.